# Using openldap authentication only for some users

Tags: pam, openldap, sssd

I am trying to set up a couple of Linux workstations (RedHat 7), and I am trying to figure out how to set up authentication against an LDAP server with some unusual requirements.

I basically know how to set up LDAP authentication using sssd, but I don't know how to restrict authentication to only certain users to meet my requirement.

To enable LDAP configuration, I would use this command line:

```
authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver="<redacted>" --ldapbasedn="<redacted>" --update --enablemkhomedir
```

This will allow all LDAP users to log on, and as far as I know works just fine. However, my requirement is that only some users from LDAP can log in, and the list of users will be supplied in a separate text file (by user login name).

More information: We have an LDAP server (Active Directory, actually) with a couple thousand users. Only about 20 of them who have a need to work on these workstations should be allowed to log on to these workstation. Unfortunately, LDAP does not include any information related to this, and I do not have control of the LDAP server. Instead, every couple of weeks, I get a text file with a list of the user names who should be allowed to log on.

How can I set up authentication to use LDAP for user name/password/user ID etc. while also restricting it to only users on this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put those users into a group, then use a `pam_access` rule in `/etc/security/access.conf` to only allow logins if the user is in that group (and also for `root`, any sysadmins, and monitoring, if necessary) e.g.

```
+ : root wheel nagios : ALL
+ : yourusergrouphere : ALL
- : ALL : ALL
```

Comment: I have no control over the LDAP server and cannot put them into a group - that's my problem!

Comment: After further research - pointing me to access.conf may still solve my problem. There are still a few pieces missing, but access.conf may be a crucial step along the way. Thanks!

Comment: To put those users into a group, then use a pam_access rule in `/etc/security/access.conf`, is this on the LDAP server or LDAP client?

Answer (score 2):

I found two ways to accomplish what I needed. The first was the one outlined by thrig. I had to add each user name individually to /etc/security/access.conf.

The second option is to specify an LDAP query string in sssd.conf:

ldap_access_filter = (|(userid=user1)(userid=user2).....)

The second solution is very tedious to build, but ends up having major performance benefits in large LDAP environments because sssd will only retrieve a few LDAP records.